# Parse local HTML python (lxml)

Tags: python, lxml, html-xml-utils

I'm trying to parse a local HTML with lxml, but I'm getting an error, but I don't know why (sorry in advance for the bad code, I'm new to this).

```
from lxml import etree, html
from StringIO import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
doc = etree.parse(StringIO("test1.html"), parser)
tree = html.fromstring(doc)
CCE = tree.xpath('//div[@data-reactid]/div[@class="browse-summary"]/h1')
URL = tree.xpath('//a[@class="rc-OfferingCard"]/@href')

print 'CCE:', CCE
print 'URL:', URL
```

And here's the error:

```
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
tree = html.fromstring(doc)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 703, in fromstring
is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: I think your html is not valid, make sure `test1.html` is valid using https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: `StringIO` is use to treats text in variable as open file - not to load file.

Comment: `html.fromstring` wants a string. You feed it the result of `etree.parse` (not a string).

Comment: Thanks, there are some little errors in attributes and elements, in fact

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need

```
tree = etree.parse("text1.html", parser)
```

without `StringIO` and `fromstring`

Comment: YES! It works perfectly! Thank you, I cannot give a feedback for your answer due to my low reputation, but it works fine!!